# localization of kinect POST creating an offline pcd model of an environment with KinFu

Tags: localization, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to use the room model (3D Map) of an environment from the kin_fu example in the pointclouds code to then view it and localize the kinect in real time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43637/localization-of-kinect-post-creating-an-offline-pcd-model-of-an-environment-with-kinfu/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2012-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest that you contact these guys: http://www.cs.nuim.ie/research/vision/data/rgbd2012/. I saw them doing it in one of their demos.
D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2012-09-12**:
Thanks. I will try that. If I get a reply I will post it here.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2012-10-02**:
Are there any updates?